# Communication Android without ADB

Tags: android, adb, smartphone

Can we communicate with an android smartphone without ADB ? to avoid activating the debug mode. Are there any other solutions ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No this is not possible, unless to make a apk and install every time.

Comment: what do you mean "communicate with an android smartphone" specifically what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

maybe this can help you ?

https://code.google.com/p/adblib/

or what are you trying to do??

//EDIT:

if you just need the logfiles maybe this..

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.jtb.alogcat&feature=nav_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDMsIm9yZy5qdGIuYWxvZ2NhdCJd

Comment: how do you establish the connection with adb ? and why u have to?

Answer (score 0):

Without adb, you can test your app on your device by manually sending the apk file in your phone memory or sd card using a data cable. You can find the apk file in the {project folder}\bin directory.